# reference gwt project from a non-gwt project

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, gwt, ant

I have two projects, one is gwt project, one is non-gwt project. And I can use gwt jar file in non-gwt project which works fine. However, I want to directly reference gwt project so I can debug gwt project java file inside of the non-gwt project. So I did following steps, but still get error:

1. in non-gwt project Build path, add gwt project on the build path.
2. in gwt project, there is a gwtProject.gwt.xml file.
   And in non-gwt project , there is a nonGwtProject.gwt.xml file.
   So I copied everything from gwtProject.gwt.xml to nonGwtProject.gwt.xml.

However, I got below error when I build gwt module.

```
R] Hint: Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries properly
```

And I noticed there is a source path like below. They should be inside of gwt project, and my question is how to reference the source path from the non-gwt project xml file?

```
<source path="web/client"/>
<source path="util/common"/>
```

non-gwt project structure:

```
com.abc.reports -- nonGwtProject.gwt.xml is under this folder
```

gwt project structure:

```
com.abc.toolkit -- gwtProject.gwt.xml is under this folder
com.abc.toolkit.web.client
com.abc.toolkit.util.common
```

Which path should I give for source path?

Comment: In GWT project client side code is converted to JavaScript that goes to `nocache.js` file. Just add this `nocache.js` file in your non-gwt project's HTML/JSP along with other GWT stub.

Comment: Keep both the project separate and do in the same way as we do for simple java project by adding jar file of another java project but its `nocahce.js` in case of GWT project for client side code only. You can copy server and shared side code directly.

Comment: Can you post the project structure to understand the location of `web/client` and `util/common`.

Comment: Is it a MAVEN project?

Comment: It must follow the [GWT standard project structure](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-doc-1-5/wiki/DevGuideDirectoriesPackageConventions).

Comment: @Braj see my structure above, thx!